# UIToolbar not displaying on iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, iphone-4

I have a UIToolbar on the bottom of my app.  On any device iPhone 5 and up it shows up correctly.  On iPhone 4s and down it does not show on the screen at all.  I have tried to add constraints but it is not helping.  I am at a lose as to why this is happening.  My app worked fine up until today.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the constraints you've to the toolbar?

Comment: Can you show some related code of toolbar?

Comment: it turns out this had to do with XCode 6 not handling constraints the same way as XCode 5.  I redownloaded XCode5 and redid the constraints and that fixed it.  Thanks for your help though.