# Bottom UIToolbar off screen on iPhone 4 and 4S

Tags: ios, xcode, controller, navigation

My problem is very similar to [UIToolbar not displaying on iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004349/uitoolbar-not-displaying-on-iphone-4-and-iphone-4s)

I am using Xcode 7 and am trying to get a 'legacy' UINavigationController based iPhone app up and running on various iPhone screen sizes. By legacy , I mean it does not use Storyboards etc. The views are loaded from an .xib.

The app is a classic UINavigationController app with UITableViewControllers but with a UIToolBar at the bottom underneath the table view.  The TableView and ToolBar are subviews of the view of the ViewController.
Works great on iPhone5/5s/6/6s. 
But on the iPhone 4/4s the toolbar is off the screen. Oddly if I rotate the screen to landscape, the toolbar appears. Rotate back, it vanishes.  I know this seems like prehistoric iOS code, but I am completely at a loss here and have wasted hours fiddling in Xcode and IB. I know I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the height of your table view is set to be a fixed height where the toolbar is visible beneath the table view on iPhone 5 and up. To get the toolbar to display on iPhone 4/4s requires reducing the height of the table view's frame using something like the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews 
{   
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (onIphone4 && portraitOrientation) {
        CGFloat height = 480 - self.toolbar.frame.size.height;
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, height); // for iPhone 4/4s
    } else if (onIphone5 && portraitOrientation) {
        CGFloat height = 568 - self.toolbar.frame.size.height;
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, height); // for iPhone 5 and up
    }
}
```

You will probably need to change the y position in the frame origin to account for the status bar and navigation bar if they are also present. In that case, the overall frame height will need to be adjusted for those changes. This is the frame-based way of adjusting view sizes.

The alternative and preferred method is to add auto layout constraints in the XIB for the toolbar and the table view in Interface Builder so that they will maintain the proper size and position relative to the screen dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.. it was the "Full Screen at Launch" checkbox in IB, for the main "UIWindow"... and I quote from Apple documentation....

"If you choose to create a window in Interface Builder, *be sure to select the Full Screen at Launch option in the Attributes inspector* so that the window is sized appropriately for the current device."
Now please excuse me while  I slam head against wall..way to waste a Sunday!